# Rspec Factory issue- conceptual problem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I'm trying to test a case in our Ruby on Rails system where we lock a user out after x failed login attempts.  The issue I'm having is trying to create a user has reached the number that 'locks' his account.  I am using Factories to create a user like so-

```
Factory.define :locked_user, :class => User do |user|
user.name                   "Test Lock"
user.email                  "lock@lock.com"
user.password               "blah1234"
user.password_confirmation  "blah1234"
user.login_count             5
end
```

Where 5 is the 'magic number'.  When I try to use something like

```
@user = Factory(:locked_user)
```

It creates a user in the database- but newly created users always have login_count set to zero, so it just logs him in the test.  When I try the .build method like so

```
@user = Factory.build(:locked_user)
```

It sets a user with login_count = 5 like I want, but then doesn't see the user as valid and won't try to log them in (ie, it gives us the 'bad user/password' error rather then 'right user/password but you are locked out' error).  I guess I'm missing something here to get RSpec to pick up the fact that this is valid user but the account should be locked.  Can someone help set me straight?  Below is the entire desribe block-

```
describe "with locked account" do
     before(:each) do
      @user = Factory.build(:locked_user)
      @attr = { :email => @user.email, :password => @user.password}
    end

  it "should not allow signin with locked account" do
    post :create, :session => @attr
    flash.now[:error].should =~ /Invalid user locked out/i
  end  
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you either set the login_count after creating the user, or stub the method that tells you if a user login is locked.

For instance, use update_attribute to force the login_count after the user has been created:

```
before(:each) do
  @user = Factory(:user)
  @user.update_attribute(:login_count, 5)
  @attr = { :email => @user.email, :password => @user.password}
end
```

Or use stubs to stub out the locked_login?, or equivalent method:

```
before(:each) do
  @user = Factory(:user)
  @user.stub(:locked_login?).and_return(true)
  @attr = { :email => @user.email, :password => @user.password}
end
```

Comment: I tried using the .update_attribute method (makes more sense given our planned implementation) but it still thinks the last_login value is 0 even after I give it the new value.  Any ideas?

Comment: That is an implementation bug. You probably have some after_save or before_save hook that is overriding that value and setting it to 0. I would recommend debugging that individual update_attribute line before moving on with the rest of this testing - write some unit tests and solve that problem first.